# Nginx+fastCGI, php displayed as comment in source code

Tags: php, nginx

First of all, this is not a duplicate, I've tried every possible variation of the answers already on Stack Overflow.

That being said, I'm facing a common issue, namely : My php code, supposed to execute through php-fpm is instead shown as text in the source of my php file.

Here's my config :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  mywebsite.com;
    root /var/www/old_bny;
    default_type text/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        #try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

This is only the last of many attempts... Any hints on how to debug/fix would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/180270/nginx-php-fpm-php-scripts-not-running ?

Comment: nope, been there, done that ;)

Comment: Four possibilities - the server is not restarting, the above config is not being read, the server name is not `mywebsite.com` or the URI does not end with `.php`. What do the access and error logs say?

Comment: the access log shows a 200, php-fpm log says nothing, the server(s) have all restarted, and the URI is `info.php`. A true mystery :) also, the config is being read, as it goes to the right root directory